# What are pairwise independent random variables that have the maximum degree of dependence possible

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am interested to know how to construct a set of pairwise independent random variables that has the maximum dependence possible, and why this specific way of construction is the best we can do.

Answer (score 3):

Choose $X$ and $Y$ to be independent and uniformly distributed random variables on $\{ 0,1 \}$ and $Z = (X+Y) \text{ mod } 2$. Then it is easy to verify that $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent, but

- $Z$ is completely determined by $(X,Y)$,
- $Y$ is completely determined by $(X,Z)$,
- $X$ is completely determined by $(Y,Z)$.

Similarly, if you want more than three random variables, let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent and uniformly distributed random variables on $\{ 0,1 \}$ and $Z = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i) \text{ mod } 2$. Then you have pairwise independence of $(X_1,\dots,X_n,Z)$, but each random variable is completely determined by the others. However, in this case, I am not sure that you really have the *maximal dependence possible* for $n > 2$ (for instance, three variables will still be independent), since I don't know a proper definition of *maximal dependence possible*.

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: thanks for your input! I think I've found one: have $2log_2 n$ independent random bits, pair them into disjoint pairs and let XNORed pairs be the random variables, and use all the non-empty subsets of this set to construct n random variables by XNOR the elements in each set. I I feel this has the maximum dependence possible, as knowing the $log_n$ RVs completely determines outcomes of all $n$ RVs. However, i need to show all pairwise independent RVs can be constructed from a set of completely independent RVs to complete the proof

Comment: I think if you want to go beyond three random variables, you really have to define how you measure the overall dependence (in order to maximize a well-defined object). "I feel this has the maximum dependence" does not seem rigorous enough. There are certain measures of dependence such as mutual information.